# Install Ubuntu MATE on Latitude 5591 SSD

Tags: dell, ssd, mate

Work got me a new Latitude 5591 with a SSD.

I tried the Ubuntu Mate 18.04.1 Live USB, and it seemed to work great, so I tried to install it, but the installer didn't seem to see the SSD.

I found a post that suggested changing from RAID to AHCI. After that, I was able to install.

But now, right after I log in, the laptop locks and won't respond to any inputs.

Have I missed a step? I appreciate any guidance. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you also updated UEFI and SSD firmware?  Perhaps similar? Dell 5230 with 3 m2 drives.
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2406057

Comment: this is uncommon. sometimes using differemt distribuions have different results in hardware recognition. if u don't mind try a different distro. Mint for example.in the end it might be quicker than struggeling with this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [other answers](https://github.com/stockmind/dell-xps-9560-ubuntu-respin/issues/5) that claim that the nvidia drivers don't properly support newer Dell laptops.

So, first I installed Ubuntu Mate 18.04.1 again, but I did NOT choose the checkbox to install third-party software and drivers.

That made the laptop bootable and would run well, but it would not shut down or restart.

The [link I posted above](https://github.com/stockmind/dell-xps-9560-ubuntu-respin/issues/5) also suggested a change to the grub config. So I added `nouveau.modeset=0` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and did `sudo update-grub`.

Now the laptop starts, runs, and shuts down properly. I haven't found any side effects yet.

@oldfred: I'll use `fwupdmgr` to update firmware.

@AlexOnLlinux: Thanks for your reply too. A different distro would have been the next thing I tried. Though, (practically) EVERYTHING is based on Ubuntu any more...

Thanks!